# Convert monthly data from one type to another

Tags: r, date, datatable, substring, lubridate

I have a column with monthly date that has such type (number of month, _, year):

```
Date
9_2018
1_2013
12_2014
```

etc.

I want to convert this date format to a date of the following form (year, month):

```
New_Date
201809
201301
201412
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `zoo::as.yearmon` to convert the date and then use `format` to get data in the required format.

```
format(zoo::as.yearmon(df$Date, "%m_%Y"), "%Y%m")
#[1] "201809" "201301" "201412"
```

Or can be done in base R as well by pasting an arbitrary date to year-month value we have.

```
format(as.Date(paste0("1_", df$Date), "%d_%m_%Y"), "%Y%m")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1_2013", 
"12_2014", "9_2018"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding zeros for month and then splitting at the "_":

```
library(stringr)

mon <- sapply(strsplit(Date, "_"), FUN="[", 1)
mon <- str_pad(mon, width=2, pad="0")
year <- sapply(strsplit(Date, "_"), FUN="[", 2)
paste0(year,mon)
[1] "201809" "201301" "201412"
```